# can't find any working sample of websocket

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, websocket

I shy to ask but I can't fins any **`working`** Visual Studio 2012 project/solution for websocket protocol in:

- Silverlight
- Asp.Net

Pleas help. And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at http://signalr.net/ yet?  If you're on the .NET platform it's a fun way to get started with websockets without getting into the details too much. They have some demo projects that you can run out of the box, and a NuGet package installer too. Check it out :)